# Chart.js is only displaying after f12 is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to display a stock chart on the webpage when it is opened, but it won't display unless i press f12

I've already tried including the code inside a function and displaying the chart when a button is pressed but it also doesn't seem to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var highlist = [];
    var lowlist = [];
    var datelist = [];
    $.getJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=G9UIQ9K1TRVBHHME", function(json) {
        var times = json["Time Series (Daily)"];
        for(var time in times)
            {
                var stock_info = times[time];
                var highItem = stock_info["2. high"];
                var lowItem = stock_info["3. low"];
                highlist.push(highItem);
                lowlist.push(lowItem);
                datelist.push(time);                                  
            }
    });
    var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext('2d');
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: datelist,
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            label: "High",
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(204, 204, 255, .2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(51, 51, 255, .7)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: highlist
            },
            {
            label: "Low",
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(0, 137, 132, .2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(0, 10, 130, .7)',
            ],
            data: lowlist
            }]
        },
    });
</script>
```

Expect the chart to show but nothing is displaying unless f12 is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getJson is an asynchronous function, so JS will send a request and then draw your chart before it gets a response.

Put all the chart stuff inside a function, and then call that function after the for loop inside your getJson callback.

Comment: No problem. I'd appreciate it if you could mark my answer as correct then.